# How to delete multiple text channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases=['d','dc'])
async def deletechannel(ctx,name: discord.TextChannel,amount):
    for i in range (int(amount)):
        channel = name
        await channel.delete()
```

it only let me delete one a time, even if a have 100 channels with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Try this

first import Greedy

```
from discord.ext.commands import Greedy
```

then

```
@client.command(aliases=['d','dc'])
async def deleteChannel(ctx, name: Greedy[discord.TextChannel]):
for i in name:
await i.delete()
```

Here is info about Greedy. [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=greedy#discord.ext.commands.Greedy)